# Why is react devtools saying my component changes due to Context changes even when it does not use useContext?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-context

I am trying to figure out why react profiler says my componenent rerenders due to context change even though it does not use useContext. As can be seen the only context it uses is from useParams not useContext, but I could not find any information on this useParam's context.

**React profiler info**
[image: React profiler info]

**React components info**

[image: React components data]

**SearchResults component**

```
import "./searchResults.css";
import Topbar from "../../components/topbar/Topbar";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Rightbar from "../../components/rightbar/Rightbar";
import Feed from "../../components/feed/Feed";
import FriendResult from "../../components/friendResult/FriendResult";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import { useParams, useLocation, useHistory, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

//return list of all users inside the database excluding the current user
export default function SearchResults() {
    const query = useParams().query;
    return ( 
      <>
        <Topbar/>
        <div className="searchResultContainer">
          <Sidebar/>
          <Feed searchQuery = {query}/>
          <Rightbar/> 
        </div>
      </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useParams` is a custom hook that uses `useContext` under the hood. You can always open their source code to read what it does and how it works. You will see that is uses `React.useContext(RouteContext)`